# Django search query for models with tags

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have models as below and I would like to select `IndexedLibrary` objects depending on its `book` name and the `tag` names of that `book`.

How can I build this query? The query below performs without including tags of the book, but I would like to join them also

```
IndexLibrary.objects.filter(book__name__icontains=KEYWORD)


class IndexedLibrary(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book,null=False,blank=False)    

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1000)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class BookTag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book,null=False,blank=False)    
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would add `tags` as a `ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True)`, remove the `book` property from `BookTag` and then query like

```
IndexLibrary.objects.filter(book__name__icontains=KEYWORD, \
    tags__name__in=['Tage Name 1', 'Tag Name 2'])
```

Especially since tags are often shared among more than one object.